# How to click on button when input type =Button in Selenium Web driver by using Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to click on button when input type is button , I am using below code, click on button is  working but data is not saved.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='button'][value='Save']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[@type='button'][@value='Save']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[@type='button']")).click();
```

And below is the development code for your reference:

```
<input id="save_btn_expe" class="edit_forms_save_btn" type="button" value="Save">
```

Comment: Try finding the element by 'Id' or 'xpath' of the element.

Comment: yes , i have already applied but azax calling on button click and Type is button then this is not working.

Comment: What do you mean actually?? Not clear what are saying??

Comment: I was trying to say that find the element with its Id or its Xpath. In selenium you can find the elements in few ways and these two are one of them. Assuming your button is showing on another button click, then, when the first button is clicked wait for some time - using this code `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` and try clicking the ajax called button.

Comment: @ Saurabh Gaur i have applied more code , button clicking is working fine but my data  is not save, because azax calling on button click so i have not found  any solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement setElement = driver.findElement(By.id("save_btn_expe"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", setElement);
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.id("save_btn_expe")).click();
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='save_btn_expe']")).click();
```

Comment: Azax calling on button and input type is button then this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

By considering your statement "click on button is working". You can use the submit method to post form data. You can use two other alternates for click. Following code is in c#:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("save_btn_expe")).submit();
// Send enter key on the element.
driver.FindElement(By.Id("save_btn_expe")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
```

Before trying the above code, check manual save to make sure there is no bug on save.

Comment: Azax calling on button click  and input type is button then submit is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an input tag element, though the type is button .click() or .submit() will not work. You have to provide the Enter key as an input. Use following code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='save_btn_expe']")).sendKeys(org.openqa.selenium.Keys.ENTER);
```

I hope this will work for you, as it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

if using `for` in DOM, the selector below work for me :

```
Selenide.$("label[for=\"save_btn_expe\"]").click();
```